# How can I get the While function to evaluate two conditions simultaneously?

Tags: functions, procedural-programming

This is probably a basic question but I'm having trouble in writing a While conditional that evaluate two conditions at the same time. I have the following code. The idea is to generate two random numbers until both of them are greater than 6

```
a = 1 ; b = 1;

While[a < 6 && b < 6, 
  a = RandomInteger[10]; 
  b = RandomInteger[10];  
  Print["a = ", a, " b = ", b]];
```

This printed for me a=8 b=1. I want b to be >6 as well. I tried a couple of variations

```
While[a < 6 ; b < 6,...]

While[{a < 6 ; b < 6},...]

While[{a < 6 && b < 6},...]

While[(a < 6 && b < 6),...]

While[a < 6 , While[ b < 6,...]]
```

None of them work! Please help a noob

Answer (score 3):

You want to use `Or` rather than `And`. Then you are printing are all of the failures and the final success.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

a = 1; b = 1; n = 1;

SeedRandom[12]

While[a < 6 || b < 6, a = RandomInteger[10]; b = RandomInteger[10]; 
 Print["Try ", n++, ": a = ", a, ", b = ", b]]

(* Try 1: a = 2, b = 4

Try 2: a = 0, b = 10

Try 3: a = 1, b = 9

Try 4: a = 7, b = 3

Try 5: a = 1, b = 10

Try 6: a = 7, b = 0

Try 7: a = 9, b = 5

Try 8: a = 4, b = 6

Try 9: a = 7, b = 2

Try 10: a = 8, b = 5

Try 11: a = 4, b = 7

Try 12: a = 8, b = 8 *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple of solutions that use the functional approach:

```
(* METHOD 1 *)

ClearAll[f1];
f1[{x_, y_}] /; Or[x < 6, y < 6] := (
    Print[{x, y}];
    f1[{RandomInteger[{0, 9}], RandomInteger[{0, 9}]}]
);
f1[{x_, y_}] := {x, y};

(*
f1[{0, 0}]
{0, 0}
{6, 4}
{3, 9}
{5, 5}
{8, 9}
*)

(* METHOD 2 *)

ClearAll[f2];
f2 = ReplaceRepeated[{x_, y_} /; Or[x < 6, y < 6] :> (
    Print[{x, y}];
    {RandomInteger[{0, 9}], RandomInteger[{0, 9}]}
)];

(*
f2[{0, 0}]
{0, 0}
{1, 5}
{4, 2}
{1, 7}
{7, 4}
{7, 7}
*)
```

Side note: Yes, I am aware that the presence of the `Print` statements makes the functions non-functional.

Answer (score 1):

While works when condition True. Stop condition is a > 6 && b > 6.
So working condition should be Not[a > 6 && b > 6]

```
a = 1; b = 1;
While[a < 6 || b < 6,
  Print[a, "   ", b];
  If[n < 6, a++, b++];
 ]
```